# Jquery DataTables (1.10) render extra footer when verticle scrollbar appears (overflow-y: auto)

Tags: jquery, css, datatables-1.10, fixed-header-tables

I am using datatables with Bootstrap 4 and everything was working fine until I tried to add a max-height and scroll vertically. I added a wrapper through the DOM setting of the datatable

```
<"feedGridContent"t>
```

This scrolls great, except my footer appears at the bottom of the page[image]

If I go to shorter page, the footer disappears if the number of rows is less then the page length, or when the scrollbar disappears. it is rendering an empty table at the bottom of my  with only the footer visible.

Any Ideas???  I have tried jquery selectors to try to hide it but have not been creative enough to figure a selector to get the added footer/table only...

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post this in case someone does something silly and has the same issue.

Before I actually posted and after looking at what code sample to insert, I noticed my issue...

```
fixedHeader: {
    footer: true
},
```

So basically, not sure why I added it but removing this statement from the Datatable config fixed the issue.